# How to dismiss loader when firebase data are received ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, loader

I have small issue when I try to dismiss my loader.

My loader works in 2 cases:

Case1: Wait 10 seconds then if no data received, it will dismiss automatically.

Case2: If data received, loader should dismissed.

My issue in the 1st case, sometime there is no internet to received data, but when I connected with internet I got this error:

[image]

Here is part of my code

```
...
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: "",
  duration: 10000
})
loader.present().then(_=>{
   this.list1= this.afd.list('/table1/');
   this.list1.subscribe(_=>{
      loader.dismiss();
   });
});
```

> note: list1 is a firebase list

So how can dismiss the loader without got that error?

Comment: What error did you get? It might be a scope problem

Comment: @Sébastien some thing like loader already dismissed/ not presented

Comment: @Sébastien i'm editing the question now

Comment: @Sébastien updated ..

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11443#issuecomment-336629022

Comment: @SurajRao nice catch ;)

Comment: @SurajRao worked

Comment: @SurajRao would you mind adding that as an answer? It may help some other SO users facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11443#issuecomment-336629022) and a workaround suggested by kaceo is:

```
this.loading.dismiss().catch();
```